# Synonym for "Instant"

Tags: synonyms

I checked the synonyms for "[Instant](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/instant)" and I found a few odd results:

**Synonyms (top 3 results) :**

> - burning
> - contemporary
> - crying

How are these words connected to the word *'Instant'*?

 A synonym is clearly defined as:

> a word (or words) or phrase that means exactly or nearly the same as another word or phrase in the same language.

How do these suggestions mean exactly or nearly what *"instant"* means ?

Comment: Personally, I think that is a terrible list of "synonyms".  "Extant" is a synonym for "instant"?!  ["Extant" just means "still in existence; still surviving."](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extant)  "Present-day"?  [That also just means "as of now; current".](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/present-day)  The only way these could mean the same things as "instant" is maybe as part of a much larger construction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hint is right on the page you link to:

[image]

As NOAD says, one meaning of *instant* is:

> **instant** (*adj.*) urgent; pressing: *an instant desire to blame others when things go wrong*

Synonyms of *pressing* include *burning*, as in:

> There was a **pressing/burning** need to get supplies to the fort.

Furthermore, [OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=crying&ls=a) says that *crying* means "demanding attention", while [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/crying) says that *a crying need for something* is *an urgent need for something*.

So, the synonym chain goes something like this:

> *instant* > *pressing* > *urgent* > *crying*

I'm having trouble thinking of a sentence where I could swap *crying* for *instant*, but I can see how certain nuances of the two words are related.

As for your "clear" definition of the word *synonym*, it's important to highlight the word *nearly*:

> a word .. that means exactly or **nearly** the same as another word or phrase

The word *crying* fits that bill, as both *crying* and *instant* can convey feelings of pressing urgency.